# Thymeleaf Swich with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm trying to build an eshop. I want to create a page that, when viewed by a *User*, only shows those items which quantity is greater than 0, but when *Administrator* viewing the same page, they can see all items and can add/edit/delete items regardless of whether the quantity is 0 or more.
I think maybe I can use Thymeleaf with Spring Security like this:

```
 <div th:switch=sec:authorize="hasAuthority('admin')">
        <div th:case="'admin'" class="tilt pic" id="whoKnows" >
        <div th:case="'user'" class="tilt pic"  th:unless="${viewAvailableWhisky.quantityWhisky} == 0">
```

but it's not working.

It's a joke? two people edit my text, but they don't know answer...

Comment: editing the question doesn't oblige to answer it, it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

Two years later.

If you would want to stick to the `th:switch` approach, this could be a way:

```
<div th:switch="${#authorization.expression('hasAuthority(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}">
    <div th:case="true" class="tilt pic" id="whoKnows">ADMIN</div>
    <div th:case="false" class="tilt pic" 
         th:unless="${viewAvailableWhisky.quantityWhisky} == 0">USER</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html:

> The sec:authorize attribute renders its content when the attribute
>   expression is evaluated to true

Just use sec:authorize directly:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('admin')" class="tilt pic" id="whoKnows"></div>
<div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('user')" class="tilt pic"  th:unless="${viewAvailableWhisky.quantityWhisky} == 0"></div>
```

Your solution doesn't work because your switch condition will resolve to true or false but not to 'admin' or 'user'. hasAuthority('admin') will resolve to true if the user has the 'admin' authority and to false if not.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14267802)

Comment: @Wildcat go ahead and tell me why this is no answer for the question. or do you want me to answer the 'it's a joke?' question?

Comment: Cause your "answer" starts with a question. If you want OP to clarify something, ask in comments first.